# gnome on windows

Tags: windows, gnome

Salaam,

I couldn't find a similar post, maybe some servers don't like this keyword combinations :)

I would like to have gnome/linux running on a windows desktop, I know that it is possible through:

1- Virtual machine, with linux/gnome installed
2- Cygwin, with gnome configured
3- other ports

As for 1, it is discarded because of memory consumption too high
As for 2, I couldn't find any working sample configuration, i found a gnome/cygwin project that is abandoned.
As for 3, an assumption of what's there but unknown up to this point->.

Thanks

Comment: This needs to be in the form of a question

Answer (score 0):

You can try colinux + Xming. There was even such a thing as "Portable Ubuntu" - http://portableubuntu.demonccc.com.ar/